# replace the HTC unlock system for a keyboard combination in Android 2.3.5?

Tags: keyboard, lock-screens, htc-sense

How can I replace the HTC-sense ringy swipy unlock mechanism for an unlock mechanism that only requires to enter a keyboard combination in Android 2.3.5? I find myself not able to do it easily on one hand and since I have a physical keyboard, I would like to be able to unlock the screen with a keyboard combination.

Comment: Let me know if this helps,

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.nolock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qcmFmLmFuZHJvaWQubm9sb2NrIl0.

Comment: [No Lock][1] as suggested in a comment does very much what I wanted and even more, and it's a lightweight application which always helps. Please reply as answer for the points!


  [1]: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.nolock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qcmFmLmFuZHJvaWQubm9sb2NrIl0

Comment: done :) you can now mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this helps,

[No Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.nolock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qcmFmLmFuZHJvaWQubm9sb2NrIl0)